# .Net Core 3 WebAPI became unresponsive after random days of usage

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core

We are experiencing a very strange issue we are not able to solve. We have an API application, made with Dot Net Core 3.1, running on an AWS EC2 instance. The APIs works perfectly fine, no errors neither anomalies or heavy load.

After a random number of days, generally after 20~40 days, they become unresponsive, and clients receive a 504 response.

Looking at the log we see the following errors are written every time you try to make a request to an endpoint:

```
"System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.WaitUntilCountOrTimeoutAsync(TaskNode asyncWaiter, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.PolicyEvaluator.AuthenticateAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.UsePathBaseMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()"
```

Raised by Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer

The application becomes functional again only after a full server restart.

The server is a Windows Server 2019 instance.

Comment: Your error comes from `AuthorizationMiddleware`, start from this part

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski after some investigations it seems related to a network failure of the machine, an EC2 instance on AWS: if I try to CURL any website on HTTPS it stuck with no response or error. Works fine instead on HTTP.